# Firebase Automated Cron Job Options Without Functions

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-functions

I have an app (Flutter using Android Studio) I am on the final stages of and I would, in an ideal world, want to include a feature to notify the user via a mobile notification if a date held against their UID is equal to today (let's use a birthday as an example).

I've spent 2 days looking in to all options, and was very close to using Cloud Functions to store a once a day cron function to notify all users, using FCM, based on the condition above - but something stopped me.

I'm very new to app building. So new that I can not confidently say I do not have a bug or infinity loop somewhere to rack up a huge bill upgrading to the Blaze plan - which without I can not use functions (I literally had credit card in hand on the upgrade page and stopped).

After 3 months of app building I feel I'm between a rock and a hard place. I don't want to launch without auto-notifications (as it's pretty key to the slickness of the app) BUT I can not risk a skies the limit, no-cap, no protection Blaze account if the worst was to happen.

It seems crazy for the effort to be put in to Firebase by Google, which to be fair helps new developers code and launch apps, to put them unnecessarily at risk or cost without automated protection. At least the Flame plan capped your spend - but I can see this is a real concern to new app developers such as myself (I've developed for the web for years). I just can't risk Blaze. I am more than happy to pay for things I use, but not to put myself at risk. Anyway I digress...

Without upgrading to Blaze - is there anyway a newbie such as myself, who is still learning the ropes, I can use FCM, and a cron job, to every day check the Cloud Firestore for users where a certain condition applies (i.e. UID date = today) - and notify them through a notification to their mobile device?

Comment: If you're looking for recommendations for products, that's off-topic for stack Overflow.  Also, Cloud Functions is really the easiest way to get this work done, and your other options are going to be just as difficult or moreso.

Comment: No not products - perhaps suggestions, tutorials, plugins etc.... I'm not looking to move away from Firebase, just work within in (as a newbie not so proficient with all the terminology) without putting myself at a cost risk I am powerless to control

Comment: But if you feel this is by far the simplest option, maybe I will have to launch without the notifications - I am probably too new to the party to start looking at more complicated options :)

Comment: All recommendations for offsite resources are [off topic for Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): "*Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow*"

Comment: Apologies - my bad

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using Google Cloud Functions and Cloud Scheduler to accomplish this.

It is worth noting that Firebase + Google Cloud provide an amount of free usage per month. It is quite likely that you could keep your usage under the limits, at least initially. Also, if you are a new Google Cloud customer, there may currently be a trial offer you can redeem for things not covered in the free tier.

- https://cloud.google.com/free
- https://firebase.google.com/pricing
- https://cloud.google.com/scheduler

Comment: Thanks Chris for the suggestion. Sounds like a good option I've seen some trial offers in the region of $300, but my big worry is something wrong in the code costing thousands of dollars overnight before I read alerts set to warn. I'm getting up to 700 reads a day and it's just me testing a small number of records - so I know I have some less than efficient code somewhere!

Comment: It may be valuable to forecast your usage. Also you may want to look into configuring Budgets and Billing Alerts.

https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/budgets

Comment: Yes the alerts are a good idea, but if something went awry at 1am I wouldn't pick up the email alert until 8am. A lot of loops can happen in 7 hours. The cautiousness is because this is my first app so new uncharted territory. I do completely understand where you are coming from though - and useful suggestions - this just is what it is I guess